# jquerymobile is using for web or for phone app?

Tags: android, ios, jquery-mobile

Can someone tell me for what i can use **jquerymobile** ?
Can i use it to make application for *ios* or *android*, or it is for websites for mobile os ?

Thanks.

Comment: Try going to jquerymobile.com - it should explain everything there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery mobile is basically web app framework but you can create desktop applications too in conjunction with phonegap.

Answer (score 1):

Please visit the link " http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/ " . Jquery mobile is not dedicated to ios or android . It supports for the most of the mobile os like blackberry,palm web os, samsung bada and soo many , to build mobile web app